# Can't change IIS AppPool recycling conditions to 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I host a WCF service on IIS via ASP.NET application.

I use static objects to hold sessions details so it is very important for me that the AppPool will not recycle its data unless I upload a new DLL or config file.

I changed the Idle Time-out (minutes) to 0 but when I try to change the Regular time intervals, Virtual memory usage and Private memory usage to 0, when I click Finish, the IIS won't save my changes.

What could be the cause of this?
How can I solve it?
Is there a work-around?

**UPDATE**

Is there a better solution than what I'm currently doing?

Comment: You can never guarantee that the app pool won't recycle. If iis decides it wants to recycle the app pool (e.g. maybe it's running out of memory) then it will regardless of settings.

Comment: Sounds like it's time to re-think your solution.

Comment: "I use static objects to hold sessions details" - my condolences.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent from losing session during Application Pool recycling, you need to store session state inside ASP.NET State Service, SQL Server DB, or a custom [Session State provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx).